# ¿Es correcto utilizar "adjuntar en" y "adjunto en"?

Tags: preposiciones

En Internet podemos encontrar ejemplos de uso de adjuntar (y adjunto) tanto con *a* como con *en*:

[Documentación a adjuntar **en** la presentación de los modelos censales](http://www.agenciatributaria.es/AEAT.internet/Inicio_es_ES/La_Agencia_Tributaria/Campanas/Censos__NIF_y_domicilio_fiscal/Empresas_y_profesionales__Declaracion_censal__Modelos_036_y_037/Informacion/Declaracion_censal__Modelos_036_y_037/Documentacion_a_adjuntar/Documentacion_a_adjuntar.shtml)

La entrada de *adjuntar* en el [Diccionario Esencial](http://lema.rae.es/desen/) no incluye ejemplos de uso.

La entrada de *adjuntar* en el DUPE de Emili Slager solo incluye usos con la preposición *a*: e.g. "adjunto al documento", "el adjunto al director".

¿Es correcto utilizar la preposición *en* con el verbo *adjuntar*?

Tampoco he encontrado respuesta a esta pregunta en los artículos del [Fundeu](http://www.fundeu.es/?s=adjuntar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"Adjuntar"**, como en el caso de **"Ofertar"**, llama mi atención constantemente. El DRAE incluye ambas, ciertamente, aun cuando la misma academia las ha calificado de barbarismos en ediciones anteriores. Su uso es más bien moderno (recibió mucha popularidad en el siglo XX). Muchos escritores se han pronunciado en contra de su uso (un ejemplo es: [Notas al castellano en la Argentina](http://www.fiile.org.ar/uploadsarchivos/_1917__notas_al_castellano_s4.pdf). Una búsqueda en Ngram o CORDE les dará muchas referencias).

En lo particular, yo evito las locuciones a toda costa porque aprendí el español cuando las palabras eran aun reprimidas. No es mi intención iniciar una discusión sobre si el uso es correcto o no sino poner el tema en contexto.

**"Adjuntar"** posee la raíz **"juntar"** (nótese que el prefijo **"ad-"** ya, por si mismo significa **"a"** o **"hacia"**). Pero, en la actualidad, también es usada como sinónimo de **"incluir"**. Dependiendo del significado la preposición es distinta.

1. Los datos que hacen falta están incluidos **"en"** el email
2. Puse los datos en el email junto **"con"** el análisis preliminar

En este caso el [DRAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0llxZ7h) no es de mucha ayuda debido a que solo captura la acepción **"juntar"** y no **"incluir"**. Si nos apegásemos estrictamente a la definición, sería posible **"con"** pero no **"en"**.

Lo cierto es que la controversia está abierta en torno a **"Adjuntar"**. Quizá, en el futuro la RAE incluya la acepción **"incluir"** en el futuro o se pronuncie al respecto en DPD.

Answer (score 1):

Dado que la definición de adjunto/a es

> Que va o está unido con otra cosa

y esa "cosa" es el email, podríamos entender que la preposición correcta debería ser "a" (adjunto a). Al enviar algo por correo tradicional, si decimos "adjunto en el sobre" en realidad queremos decir "adjunto al documento que va en el sobre". Si no, dependiera de otro documento estaríamos enviando algo, en lugar de adjuntarlo.

La verdad es que soy culpable del uso de vez en cuando de "adjunto en", como si el adjunto fuera *dentro* del email. La confusión parece estar aquí servida por la pregunta: "qué es exactamente el email?" Cuando mando un correo electrónico con una foto, estoy adjuntando esa foto al *texto* de mi correo y todo ello va en el correo electrónico, o lo estoy adjuntado directamente al correo en sí? Podríamos hacer la analogía con las cartas que recibimos en el correo tradicional. Una carta, que se compone de un sobre, en el que dentro viene... la carta.

Como *email* recoge tanto el sistema de transmisión como el mensaje transmitido, cabría decir:

> Adjunto al email (mensaje) en el email (sistema de transmisión) un documento

Si damos por bueno que podemos decir "adjunto en el medio de transmisión" (y que se sobreentiende el documento principal al que los demás van adjuntos)

> Adjunto en el sobre las fotos (para describir dos fotos que van con el formulario de la petición)
>
> Adjunto en el envío [otros documentos de menor importancia]

entiendo que podemos usar `adjunto en el email`, pero deberíamos favorecer `adjunto al email`.

Comment: Entonces en la oración _documentos a adjuntar en la presentación de los modelos censales_ no es tanto que se esté usando mal la preposición como que se hace un uso "extraño" o quizá solo redundante de _la presentación_: _documentos a adjuntar al modelo censal (cuando se presente/entregue este modelo)_ ¿correcto?

Comment: @Lucas, no soy ni un experto ni filólogo, así que harías bien en dudar y comprobar cualquier cosa que diga por aquí. Creo que en el ejemplo de tu pregunta la "presentación del modelo" es una **solicitud** para obtener un documento (DNI o similar), y por tanto el sentido es "documentación a adjuntar (a la solicitud) en las peticiones/solicitudes de este tipo". Entiendo que se hace para evitar la repetición, y que el uso es indistinguible de "documentación a aportar".